# How to map generic struct type in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, struct, automapper

I want to map `MyEntity` to `MyModel`. The first is given by an ORM generator which cannot be modified.
Of course AutoMapper is not able to map `Id<> -> long` without any mapping definition.

```
public class MyEntity
{
  public Id<MyEntity> Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Id<MyFooEntity> FooId { get; set; }
  public Id<MyBarEntity> BarId { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public long FooId { get; set; }
  public long BarId { get; set; }
}

public struct Id<T>
{
  private long _internalId { get; set; }
  public long ToLong() => _internalId;
}
```

What's working is the following:

```
CreateMap<MyEntity, MyModel>()
  .ForMember(d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ToLong())
  .ForMember(d.FooId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ToLong())
  .ForMember(d.BarId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ToLong());
```

I have a lot of entities and dozens of id properties within one entity. What I like to do is defining a generic struct mapping `Id<> -> long`. But this seems not possible so far. I tried out `TypeConverter`, `ITypeConverter<,>` and other things. The closest I get was this, but then AutoMapper complaint that `Id<>` is not a reference type and cannot be used as `System.Object`:

```
CreateMap(typeof(Id<>), long).ConvertUsing((s, d) => s.ToLong());
```

Any advice how to do this? Is there no way to define global mappings like the one already exist like `int -> string`, `int -> long`, ...

Comment: `ConvertUsing(s =>...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. But you need to modify the `Id<T>` struct.

As far as I can understand you are using some generator to generate the source files. `MyEntity` for example.
After generating the classes you need to manually modify `Id<T>` struct. It should have an interface like this for example:

```
public interface IId
{
    long ToLong();
}

public struct Id<T> : IId
{
    private long _internalId { get; set; }
    public long ToLong() => _internalId;
}
```

Now you can create the configurations like this, and it will map all `Id<T>` types in the classes.

```
configuration.CreateMap<MyEntity, MyModel>();

configuration.CreateMap<IId, long>()
                .ConvertUsing(x => x.ToLong());
```

Comment: Nitpicking. `x` should be `source` or `s`.

Comment: Yes, that's better